# is reusing the pointer from glMapBufferRange undefined?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using a uniform buffer via mapBufferRange and updating every frame as follows (assuming the buffer and bufferbase are already bound correctly):

```
    float* uboBlock0 = reinterpret_cast<float*>(
        glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0,
        buffSizeInFloats, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT));

    // cache it here and dont map/unmap for test - float* uboBlock0 = getUboBlockMemory();
    memcpy(uboBlock0, obj, buffSize);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER);
```

However if instead of mapping the buffer before using it , i simply cache `float* uboBlock0` , it still updates correctly every frame.  Even if i switch uboBlocks, and update them separately it still updates correctly. It even works on two separate nvidia cards. I read the opengl spec on mapping buffers but i cant see any description of this behavior (https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf 6.3) so i wonder if im just getting 'lucky' and should not expect it to work , or if that is ok?

Comment: I would expect that any time you switch between shader programs, GL might map the pipeline differently. Do you have more than one shader program in your application?

Comment: @sevatitov Yes I have 2 shader programs , one uses the first ubo block , the other uses the 2nd ubo block.  It doesnt seem to have any problem , but i might be in undefined territory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely undefined behavior which only seems to work by accident on your implementaion.

The [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf)
unambiguously states in section 6.3.1 "Unmapping Buffers":

> Unmapping a mapped buffer object invalidates the pointer to its data store

You must never use the pointer to the mapped buffer after you unmapped it.

However, with fairly modern GL, the [`ARB_buffer_storage`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/buffer_storage.txt) functionality is available as a core feature, which allows you to *persistently* map a buffer object. In that case, you can use the buffer in the GL *while it is still mapped*. You of course have to manually synchronize all accesses to that memory region, so that the data doesn't get overwritten before the GL finished processing it.